# HttpClientFactory response times taking increasingly longer

Tags: c#, httpclientfactory

I've just added in the new recommended way of using HttpClients which is to use the HttpClientFactory integrated with Polly

Here is my DI

```
        services.AddHttpClient("ThirdParty", client =>
        {
            //commented out for the purpose of this question

            //client.Timeout =
            //    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configProvider.OverallTimeout); 

        });
```

Here is service provider code

```
            using (var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("ThirdParty"))
            {

                 ....

                 //write log for start time

                 var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

                 //write log for end time

                 ....
             }
```

Now the service provider code above is in a class that is called a number of times, say 6 times for each request that comes into the service

The example test I have run is to fire a request in to the service, which in turn calls the service provider class 6 times, to fire off 6 separate requests to a third party to retrieve responses.

I also set up the third party to have a 5 second delay, therefore what I'm expecting to happen is all 6 requests are triggered at the same time, and all responses are returned after 5 seconds, as the client factory supposedly creates http clients transiently

What I'm finding however is that the requests seem to pair up in their response times i.e. the first two take 5 seconds, the second two take 10 and the last two take 15, even though they do in fact all get fired off at the exact same time

If I change the code to be

*using (var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("randomString"))...* 
(so it doesn't refer to the "ThirdParty" custom configuration in DI, (even though that itself doesn't do anything yet))

it works fine and all responses return after 5 seconds.

Also if I change the code to be what I had before

*using (var client = new HttpClient())...*

this also works as expected and all responses return after 5 seconds

So it seems it has something to do with having a custom setup for the DI.

Any ideas?

I've also tried using TypedClients rather than the above method of NamedClients and I get the same results

***UPDATE***

This problem only occurs when hosted in a service fabric application

Comment: Could you put some logging code in the AddHttpClient lambda to see if/how often that code gets called?

Comment: It gets called once for each client created, so 6 times for the above example

Comment: Could you edit the q to post as much of the configuration of the client `"ThirdParty"` as possible? (obviously without any sensitive details).  For instance, we can't see in the q at the moment how the Polly policies have been applied/configured on the client named `"ThirdParty"`

Comment: There isn't any configuration. I've stripped it all out to literally what you can see above and the problem still exists

Comment: Thanks @MartyBalmer. It's useful to know the Polly policies are out of the mix.

Comment: Hi Marty, are you using the reverse proxy in Service Fabric or calling an http endpoint directly? If using Reverse Proxy, check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverse-proxy-diagnostics